# Node.js Express - calling next() after proxying the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-proxy

I'm writing the Express.js application, which should route the request to some proxy server as a last step in the pipeline. I've used `http-proxy` proxying library, since it supports websockets. The problem is that I need to continue working with my application after the request is redirected, so as to collect some info which I'll be using for logging (response time for api call etc.). The idea was to call `next()` function after request is proxied, which should return me to the first middleware in the stack?(please correct me if I'm wrong) and then calculate the time difference between the starting point and the current one.

After calling `proxy.web(req, res, {target: serviceAddress});` and `next()`right after it - I get the error:

```js
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at d:\WebStorm Projects\api-gateway\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\passes\web-outgoing.js:85:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Array.writeHeaders (d:\WebStorm Projects\api-gateway\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\passes\web-outgoing.js:84:35)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (d:\WebStorm Projects\api-gateway\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\passes\web-incoming.js:149:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:426:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:317:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
```

Is there a solution for keeping working after `proxy.web(...)` is called? Or in case my approach is wrong, could anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: I haven't used this proxy module. It sounds like when a request is proxied its ending the request and the response is now being piped/sent back to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `next()` after sending a response, since you actively *don't want* the remaining middleware (which will also try to send a response) to run.

Instead, you should put all of your logging middleware first.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But in that case, what will the approach be to calculate the time spent on proceeding all of middlewares? My idea was to put my Calculating middleware as the first in the stack, then to create the `new Date()` object and call `next()` - after proceeding all middlewares and finally proxy the request I thought to call `next()` again, which should return me to the first middleware, where I could create the second `new Date()` object and calculate the difference.

Comment: @OstapLisovyj: That won't actually work, since most serving middleware is async.  The typical way to do this, AFAIK, is to proxy `res.end()` to see when the response is sent.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little bit confused here, should this be smth like `proxy.web(req, res.end(), {target: serviceAddress});` ? The future requirement is to log every API call with all relevant info and to perform other API call to some endpoint based on that information.

Comment: No; I mean that your logging middleware should wrap `res.end()` so it can find out when the response is actually sent.

Comment: However, researching further, you don't need to do any of that; you should just handle the `finish` event. https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L523

Comment: @OstapLisovyj: Exactly.